# How can I raise a single-step landing with access from two sides?

Tags: stairs

I just moved into a townhome. I have this single step down to go to the living room bathroom. Any ideas on what I can do to fix this?

[image: living room takes a step down then back up to bathroom]

Comment: Your picture appears to show stairs descending. Does the naive solution of raising the floor wreck the rise of a top stair? Is the lower floor area big enough that you could add another stair? Would the rise of this stair be within 3/8" of the other stairs? Such a "fix" feels like 1 step forward and 2 steps back. Feels like a safety hazard.

Comment: You didn't notice this before purchasing?

Comment: HOAs are generally not concerned with interior modifications, unless they involve modifying structural components.

Comment: @RMDman I did. It was not a deal breaker, still isn't. It's just a nice to have.

Comment: @popham where I'm standing is the stairs. Ahead of me to the left is the bathroom door, closed. Before it is the entrance to the living room. Do you think there are any options without having to add a riser? Or if there is a ramp or something of the sort?

Comment: Have you considered cutting a new door into the bathroom? How disruptive would such a door be to the bathroom or the living room? If you label your picture with which door goes where and add information about that wall and the bathroom layout, then you should get a "cut a new door" answer.

Comment: Can you show us a reverse angle?

Comment: Need different pictures to understand what is the arrangement.  If elderly people are having trouble, consider grab bars. We have enough in our house to qualify as a gibbon rescue facility.

Comment: Perhaps I just woke up, but what is the actual problem here? What needs fixing?

Answer (score 1):

Picture is less than clear on the relationship of the bathroom to what's pictured, but if it's either down to the bathroom, or down between and back up to the bathroom, the solution is to raise the floor. That assumes you have adequate ceiling height to be able to raise the floor and still meet code minimum ceiling heights.

Raising the floor in a bathroom is a fairly major remodel, but not particularly difficult. If it's only a half bath it is much easier than if there's a tub or shower to deal with as well.

Answer (score 1):

Working on the premise that you want to step from the room on the left to the room ahead, at the same level, a triangular fill on the top step of the stairs could suffice. It would end up similar to a winding staircase step, and still leave the right-hand part of the 'well' as original, leaving room for that to be the 'top but one' step.